# .NET Core 3.0 Can't be Selected In Visual Studio Build Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

.NET Core 3.0 Can't be Selected In Visual Studio Build Framework

Visual Studio refuses to show .NET Core 3.0 in the "Target Framework" dropdown menu in the Properties -> Application menu.

I have already installed .Net Core 3.0 to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 or higher is needed to be installed in order to use .NET Core 3.0 Framework in your project.

[Prerequisites to develop .NET Core apps with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore30#prerequisites-to-develop-net-core-apps-with-visual-studio)

If you insist using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, You need to enable "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK" from `Visual Studio's tools | Options | Project and Solutions | .NET Core`